# Help proving a theorem about node ordering of a directed multigraph

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs, multigraphs

We a have [polytree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytree) $G = (V, E)$. Note that every vertice $v_i$ can only have one outgoing edge.

[image: G]

Now lets add a new type of edge which we call an red edge. $R$ is the set of all these edges.

So we have a new graph $G = (V, E, R)$.
My goal is to find a order $O = v_1, ..., v_n$, which is

1. $(v_i, v_j) \in E$, $i < j$ (Just like a regular topological order)
2. $(v_i, v_j) \in R$, $i < j$ OR $i > z$ if there exists an edge $(v_i, v_z)$. Which is to say for every red edge $(v_i,v_j)$ then $v_i$ must either come before $v_j$ or after $v_j$'s child in the order

Lets call such an order a red topological order.

For example:

[image]

Here a red topological order would be 2130 while 3210 is a topological order but it does not satisfy the condition for the red edge (2,3) as 2 comes inbetween 3 and 0.

We can note that if any of the following is true for a graph $G$ then it has no red topological order:

1. $R$ contains a cycle between nodes with a common child

   [image]
2. $R$ contains $(v_i, v_j)$ and $(v_j, v_i)$ AND if they share a common grandchild $v_x$ then $R$ contains $(v_i, v_y)$ where $v_y$ is every regular edge between $v_j$ and $v_x$. For example, in the figure below
   $R$ contains $(2, 3)$ and $(3, 2)$. Their common grandchild is $0$. $1$ is the node between $2$ and $0$. $R$ contains $(3, 1)$. As we can see the graph has no red topological ordering.

   [image]

So we know that if G has a red topological order $\implies$ $(1)$ and $(2)$ is not true for G which I dont have a problem proving.
My suspicion is that if $(1)$ and $(2)$ is not true for $G$ $\implies$ $G$ has a red topological order

This would be nice to prove because then we know that if (1) and (2) is not true for $G$ $\iff$ $G$ has a red topological order.

---

My two questions is:

1. How would I go on to prove or disprove that if $(1)$ and $(2)$ is not true for $G$ $\implies$ $G$ has a red topological order?

---

I could disprove it by finding a graph G where (1) and (2) is not true BUT still has no red topological order, but I haven't been able to do that.

---

Ive tried proving it similar to how one proves that if a graph is a DAG then it has a topological order. But Ive only found proofs by induction and cant to do this in my case.

---

And thirdly Ive tried this strategy:

$G = (V, E, \emptyset)$.
Let $A = $ all graphs that can be created by adding red edges to $G$ with atleast one red topological order. 
Let $B = $ all graphs created by adding red edges to $G$ where (1) and (2) is not true.

Then I want to prove that $A = B$ by proving that $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$.
Proving $A \subseteq B$ is no problem as this is the same as proving G has a red topological order $\implies$ $(1)$ and $(2)$ is not true for G

But proving $B \subseteq A$???

---

2. Can I formulate the problem differently so it is easier to prove?

---

Comment: Thanks for the input. Ill check out linear extensions. Any examples on how I could make it cleaner? Ive tried my best in doing so.

Comment: Its not important don't worry about, however I'm not understanding what a "red" topological order, its a topological order with what property?

Comment: It is a topological order yes $v_1, ..., v_n$ with the property that for all red edges $(v_i, v_j)$, $i<j$ OR $i>z$ if there exists a regular edge $(v_j, v_z)$.

Which is to say for every red edge $(v_i, v_j)$ then $v_i$ must either come before $v_j$ or after $v_j$'s child in the order.

Comment: Wouldn't every topological order satisfy that property then? Since they all must have $i<j$ whenever $(v_i,v_j)$ is an arc? And you're writing $i<j$ or $i>z$

Comment: Im sorry, there was a mistake in how I defined it. Ive updated the post and my comment.

Comment: With the new definition not every topological order satisfy it. For example $3210$ in the second picture is a topological order but it does not satisfy the condition for the red edge  $(2, 3)$ as $2$ comes inbetween $3$ and $0$.